# Global Styles not working in iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I posted this in the Xamarin Forums but there have been no replies.
I have the following global styles defined in app.xaml and applied on a content page (see attached). This works as expected in Android and UWP, but doesn't work in iOS. In Android and UWP the background is dark grey with a padding of 20. In iOS the background is white with no padding. None of the styles work at all in iOS, but the colors defined at the top do work in all platforms.

app.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Rhyme4RhymeApp.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="backgroundColor">#3F3F3F</Color>
            <Color x:Key="navBackgroundColor">#232323</Color>
            <Color x:Key="textColor">#ffffff</Color>
            <Color x:Key="textColorAccent">#191919</Color>
            <Color x:Key="imageBackgroundColor">#191919</Color>


            <Color x:Key="DarkGrey">#191919</Color>
            <Color x:Key="Grey">#3F3F3F</Color>
            <Color x:Key="LightGrey">#6a6a6a</Color>
            <Color x:Key="White">#ffffff</Color>
            <Color x:Key="Orange">#f77e4f</Color>
            <Style x:Key="pageStyle" TargetType="Page" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#3F3F3F" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="20" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="NavStyle" TargetType="Page">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#383838" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="20" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="semiTransparentColor" TargetType="Layout">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#000000" />
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".9"/>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="masterDetailMenuStyle" TargetType="Page">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#3F3F3F" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="Button" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="#191919" />
                <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#191919" />
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#ffffff" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="linkStyle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#f77e4f" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="Header1LabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#ffffff" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="28" />
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold"/>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="Header2LabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#ffffff" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="Header3LabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#ffffff" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold"/>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="Header4LabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#ffffff" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="quoteLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#ffffff" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="28" />
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Italic"/>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="albumLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#ffffff" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="23" />
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold"/>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="artistLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#ffffff" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold"/>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="standardLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#ffffff" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="imageBackground" TargetType="Image">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#afafaf" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="artistListItem" TargetType="TextCell">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#ffffff"/>
            </Style>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Content Page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Rhyme4RhymeApp.NewQuotesPage" Style="{DynamicResource pageStyle}">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout x:Name="mainStack">
            <ActivityIndicator x:Name="loader" Color="{DynamicResource White}" IsEnabled="True" IsVisible="True" IsRunning="True" />
            <Label x:Name="lblAddedHeader" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="{DynamicResource White}" />
            <Label x:Name="lblNoResults" Text="" FontSize="Default" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="{DynamicResource White}" IsVisible="False" />
            <ListView x:Name="QuotesListView" AutomationId="WhatsNewLVQuotes" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Grey}"></ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: It works on my side , what is the version of your Visual studio and Xamarin?

Comment: Visual Studio Community 2017 version 15.5.5

Comment: Try to update to the latest ,since it is 15.7now

Comment: , Xamarin 4.8.0.760

Comment: I'll give updates a shot. I am new-ish to Xamarin, but in the few months I have been using it I have experienced some issues related to updating. That's why I have stuck with a version that seems stable.

Comment: Updating Visual Studio didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your XAML code with this please:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Rhyme4RhymeApp.NewQuotesPage" Style="{StaticResource pageStyle}">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout x:Name="mainStack">
            <ActivityIndicator x:Name="loader" Color="{StaticResource textColor}" IsEnabled="True" IsVisible="True" IsRunning="True" />
            <Label x:Name="lblAddedHeader" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="{StaticResource textColor}" />
            <Label x:Name="lblNoResults" Text="" FontSize="Default" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="{StaticResource textColor}" IsVisible="False" />
            <ListView x:Name="QuotesListView" AutomationId="WhatsNewLVQuotes" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource backgroundColor}"></ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but changing DynamicResource to StaticResource didn't work.

Comment: I think you should not use Color Name as key. I have updated my code please try once it.

Comment: Srusti, going back to my original problem, it is the styles that aren't working.